# Differential equation whose solution are circles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a differential equation, which has as solutions circles of radius $r$. And the equation needs to be of the form $F(y'',y',y)=0$.

The equation $$(x-x_0)^2 +(y-y_0)^2 = r$$

describes a circle of radius $r$ centered at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. If we differentiate this relation twice with respect to $x$, we have the equation $$2+2y''(y-y_0)+2(y')^2=0$$

which is in the correct form. I think this is too simple to be correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want $r^2$, not $r$, on the right side of the equation for a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential equation is satisfied by any circle of any radius whose centre has $y$ coordinate $y_0$.  I would interpret the question as saying that you want $x_0$ and $y_0$ to be arbitrary but $r$ to be fixed.  So you want to take your original equation and its first and second derivatives and eliminate $x_0$ and $y_0$. I get

$$ (y')^6 + 3 (y')^4 - r^2 (y'')^2 + 3 (y')^2 + 1 = 0$$

Comment: Is the logic behind this, that we may invert the process. That is, we start with this differential equation and end up with out original relation for circles?

Comment: @Robert Israel The equation you obtain can be written $((y')^2+1)^3=r^2(y'')^2$ with a clear connection with the formula giving the radius of curvature (see my recent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4824154/305862))