# Find a differential equation whose solution is a family of circles with centers at (h,k) and of fixed radius. Tenenbaum and Pollard Problem 1.4.20

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

I know $r^2 = (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2$ (A)

Differentiate (A)

$0 = 2(x-h) + 2(y-k)^2y'$

$0 = x - h + (y-k)^2y'$ (B)

Differentiate B

$0 = 1 + 2(y-k)y'^2 + (y-k)^2y''$ (C)

At this point I can solve for h, solving for k I think I would have to expand the terms in (C). I am unable to get the answer: $[1 + y'^2]^3 = r^2(y'')^2$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature)) for the radius of curvature :

$$R=\frac1r=\frac{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}{y''}$$

Why is it necessary to square this relationship to have the final answer ? In order to take into account the upper and the lower part of the circles ( a circle has two cartesian equations).

Comment: Any comment, two days later ?